# Is there a python interface to iptables?

Tags: python, linux, sockets, networking, iptables

Im trying to retrieve the current iptables chains configured on the system via python.  If I strace the iptables command, it outputs:

```
strace iptables -L INPUT
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW)  = 3
getsockopt(3, SOL_IP, 0x40 /* IP_??? */, "filter\0\377`\2\351\1\0\210\377\377\210}\313\276\0\210\377\377\354\206\0\201\377\377\377\377"..., [84]) = 0
```

full output here: http://pastebin.com/e7XEsaZV

In python I create the socket obj and try to call getsockopt and it errors:

```
>>> s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_RAW)
>>> s.getsockopt(socket.SOL_IP, 0x40)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#46>", line 1, in <module>
    s.getsockopt(socket.SOL_IP, 0x40)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
>>>
>>> s = socket.socket(2, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_RAW)
>>> s.getsockopt(socket.SOL_IP, 0x41)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#48>", line 1, in <module>
    s.getsockopt(socket.SOL_IP, 0x41)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
>>>
```

Is this just not possible?

Comment: Since your question is regarding `python`, I removed the `C` tag.

Comment: I seem to be missing the relationship between `iptables` and your python socket... perhaps a dumb question, but would you mind elaborating on the relationship between the two?

Comment: @Mike I might be missing something major I'm just trying to emulate the iptables command in Python and looking at the strace on the iptables command, I assumed (im not really a developer) that the getsockopt is how the current iptables configured in the kernel are retrieved. I might be WAY wrong, but i didn't see any ioctls etc.

Comment: when you say emulate iptables, what specifically are you trying to emulate in python?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Have you seen [python-iptables](https://github.com/ldx/python-iptables)?

> Python-iptables provides python bindings to iptables under Linux. Interoperability with iptables is achieved via using the iptables C libraries (libiptc, libxtables, and the iptables extensions), not calling the iptables binary and parsing its output.

Comment: i SWEAR i looked for this before trying to reinvent the wheel. Again, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for error 22 is obvious. `getsockopt()` call with type `IPT_SO_GET_INFO` requires third argument of a pointer to `struct ipt_getinfo`. The struct has include file in my Linux at `/usr/include/linux/netfilter_ipv4/ip_tables.h`.

Further, there are more requirements. The buffer size given for `getsockopt()` call needs to match the size of struct, in my machine that is 84 bytes. Why this call really fails is the requirement of struct member `.name` **must** indicate which table you're interested in querying. Unspecified size and random bytes a table name will result in this error 22.

With Python, ultimately all this fails as there is no API for entering user defined bytes as an argument for `getsockopt()`. Assuming `IPT_SO_GET_INFO` would work, the natural next step would be to read all the chains of a table with a `IPT_SO_GET_ENTRIES`, which in Python is also impossible. Python's `getsockopt()` won't allow buffers larger than 1024 bytes. In any real Linux using IPtables, the chain rules can easily exceed that 1 KiB limit.

A good C example on how to read IPtables rules is at https://github.com/mozilla/rr/blob/master/src/test/netfilter.c