# Python interface to view/modify IP routing rules

Tags: python, linux, routes, ip, subprocess

I'm trying to find a Pythonic interface to what the `ip route`-style commands do on Linux, similar to how [`python-iptables` is a nice Pythonic interface to `iptables`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891779/is-there-a-python-interface-to-iptables) which directly calls the C library functions, rather than using `subprocess` to call and parse the output of running `/usr/sbin/iptables`. Does such a module exist?

If not, what would be the best way (preferably not involving `subprocess`-parsing) to do the following in Python:

- Get the machine's IP routing table
- Add a new rule to the IP routing table
- Delete a rule from the IP routing table?

Comment: You probably don't want to hear this, but I think you're better off parsing the output of shell commands.  The routines controlling all this behind those shell commands are probably not very portable.  Keep in mind: Parsing the output of shell commands is an utter mess on Windows, but on *ix, it really works quite well.

Comment: @dstromberg I suppose that's the way it'll have to be

Answer (score 11):

Did you try [`pyroute2`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyroute2)? Pyroute2 is a pure Python netlink and Linux network configuration library. It requires only Python standard modules and no other 3rd party libraries. Later it can change, but the dependency tree will remain as simple as possible.